# Why does binding my radiobuttons to application settings change their behaviour when clicked?

Tags: .net, winforms, radio-button, application-settings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using ApplicationSettings to store Checked property for WinForms RadioButtons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937281/using-applicationsettings-to-store-checked-property-for-winforms-radiobuttons)

I have three radiobuttons in a groupbox. When they are not bound to application settings, they behave normally.

After binding each of their checked properties to application settings, the following happens: I have to click an unchecked radiobutton two times to have it checked. After the first click, all three are unchecked.

I also tried binding only two of them, but the behaviour is the same.

Can anyone please help with this?

Thanks.

I also asked on [MSDN Visual Basic General Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/deeb364e-fbe4-4c3f-8242-47e5171d3ca8).

Comment: Are you confusing radiobuttons and checkboxes?

Comment: @leppie, no. These are definitely radiobuttons, round ones.

Comment: Can you supply the details of the Binding? Ie the relevant properties on the rb buttons and how it looks in app.config

Comment: @Henk, it is only the Checked property of each radiobutton that is bound. Unfortunately, the project is on my computer at home. I will edit the question with the app.config deatils tonight. Thanks.

Comment: OOPS! I found almost the exact same question already on StackOverflow, and an answer has already been marked as correct by the asker. *I hope it will work for me when I test it tonight.* Somebody with enough rep should merge the questions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/937281/using-applicationsettings-to-store-checked-property-for-winforms-radiobuttons.

Comment: The marked answer did not work for me, but the second answer provided a link to an explanation of the problem. It is a known problem. I have come up with my own answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add the following event handler to the Click event of each of the three RadioButtons (of which the Checked properties are bound to Application Settings) in your GroupBox:

```
Private Sub RadioButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles tomRadioButton.Click, dickRadioButton.Click, harryRadioButton.Click
    If sender.Checked = False Then
        sender.Checked = True
    End If
End Sub
```

It works, even though it takes a half-second for an unckecked RadioButton to be checked after you click it.

The reason for the problem was explained two years ago (in 2008) in section 5 of the [Surviving WinForms Databinding](http://turbulentintellect.blogspot.com/2008/07/surviving-winforms-databinding.html) post on the Turbulent Intelect blog (Thank you, [ohadsc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67824/ohadsc), for the link):

> **Rule 5: Don't bind to clickable Radio Buttons**
>
> I know how great it would be if you
>   could just bind your bunch of radio
>   buttons to an enum property. I really
>   do. You think you're just going to
>   hook up some Format and Parse events
>   to translate back to your enum, and
>   all will be well. It would be so darn
>   convenient, if it actually worked. But
>   WinForms just isn't cut out for this.
>   For 3 full releases now (or is it 3.5
>   releases?), this has been the case.
>   It's because of the event order, which
>   is not something that MS can go
>   switching up without causing thousands
>   of developers to get really cheesed
>   off.
>
> The problem really comes down to the
>   fact that unlike other controls' data
>   properties, the Checked property of a
>   radio button doesn't actually change
>   until focus leaves the radio button.
>   And as with all WinForms controls the
>   focus doesn't actually leave the radio
>   button until after focus is given to
>   another control, and in fact not until
>   after the Click event of the newly
>   focused control has fired. The result
>   of this, as it pertains to radio
>   buttons, is that if you try to bind to
>   them, **the bound properties in your
>   datasource will actually lag your
>   radio buttons' visual state by one
>   click**. If you have just two radio
>   buttons, the datasource will be
>   exactly opposite the visible state,
>   until you click somewhere else that
>   doesn't trigger an action that
>   references those datasource
>   properties. Which can make this a
>   really infuriating bug to track down.
>   I almost thought I was hallucinating.
>
> Now, in all honesty, it's possible to
>   make it work. But it is the kludgiest
>   kludge that ever kludged. Okay maybe
>   it's not that bad... but it's a messy
>   hack for sure. It takes a lot of work
>   for something that really should
>   already be available. As near as I can
>   tell, the only way to solve this
>   problem without giving up the
>   databinding mechanism is to
>   essentially make your own RadioButton
>   control, with a property change and
>   event order that is actually useful.
>   You can either write one from scratch,
>   or sub-class RadioButton and override
>   all the event logic with custom
>   message handling.