# Binding RadioButtons to boolean application settings breaks default RadioButton behavior

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I have a form with three `RadioButtons` (`radioButton1`, `radioButton2`, and `radioButton3`):

[image: form with three radio buttons]

In my application settings, I have three boolean values (`Value1`, `Value2`, and `Value3`):

[image: application settings]

I bind the `Checked` property of each `RadioButton` to one of the three values in the application settings.  That is, I bind `radioButton1.Checked` to `Value1`, `radioButton2.Checked` to `Value2`, and `radioButton3.Checked` to `Value3`:

[image: properties window for radioButton1]

These bindings change the behavior of the `RadioButtons`.  Without the bindings, the `RadioButtons` show the expected behavior where clicking on an unchecked `RadioButton` unchecks the checked one and checks the clicked one.  With the bindings, clicking an unchecked `RadioButton` unchecks the checked one but does *not* check the clicked one.  It takes a second click to check the desired button.

Why is this happening?  How can I use data bindings to application settings without messing up the check/uncheck behavior of the `RadioButtons`?

Comment: You could on loading the form make the radio buttons equal the required bool, then when you change a radio button use its event handler to change the value of the bool you want it to be bound to as a work around.

Comment: @karlsweeney, if I understand your comment correctly, you're saying I could bypass databinding entirely and use the CheckedChanged event to set the settings manually?  That is an OK workaround that I might try if I can't get things working with databinding.  Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 2):

I can guess that this happens only for `RadioButton2` and `RadioButton3` where the value in Settings is set to false. Radiobutton1 should have the desired funcionality.

All you have to do is to set the scope of settings from `User` to `Application`

Comment: @apomeme, your suggested change (setting the scope of the settings from `User` to `Application`) works, but I have no idea why.  Can you add a little more explanation to your answer?  (I don't understand how the first sentence relates.)

Comment: have a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/937281/using-applicationsettings-to-store-checked-property-for-winforms-radiobuttons

Comment: Thanks; that was a useful link.  I think I understand a little better why `RadioButtons` are problematic.  I didn't see anything there about setting the scope of the settings, so your solution is still somewhat mystifying.