# How can I achieve the same functionality as a WebForms RadioButtonList using WinForms RadioButton controls?

Tags: winforms, radio-button, radiobuttonlist

I would like to create a user control that groups several `RadioButton` controls, and has a value property that indicates which `RadioButton` is checked. I could achieve this quite easily if not for not having a clue how to provide a much needed data binding capability for this control, especially just for the `Value` property. How should I go about this?

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2394429/52249) will help.  Look for the Selected property and bind a numeric value to it, which corresponds to a Tag value in one of the RadionButtons in the set.

Comment: @JayRiggs Why not make this an answer?

Comment: I don't have more to offer than the link and the (rather obvious!) remarks in my comment so I figure that doesn't justify a full-blown answer.  I hope it helped.

Comment: @JayRiggs You might as well use that as an answer - the bounty is busy expiring.

Comment: I appreciate the thought but I wouldn't be happy with that as an answer.  I'm glad you asked it though (I upvoted it) and I'm glad I found that answer because I can see having this issue in the future.