# DataBinding cannot find a row in the list that is suitable for all bindings using RadioButton Group with over 9 in the group

Tags: winforms, radio-group

I am using the technique described  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/675137/best-way-to-databind-a-group-of-radiobuttons-in-winforms) to add Groups of my radio buttons to my C# winforms application.

The technique works beautifully until I try a radio button with a tag greater than 9.

In this case an error occurs when i click the radio button

> System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled   HResult=-2146233079
>   Message=DataBinding cannot find a row in the list that is suitable for
>   all bindings.   Source=System   StackTrace:
>          at System.ComponentModel.ReflectPropertyDescriptor.SetValue(Object
>   component, Object value)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.BindToObject.SetValue(Object value)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Binding.PullData(Boolean reformat, Boolean force)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Binding.Target_PropertyChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
>          at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)
>          at SBD.VivSnap.UI.RadioGroupBox.radioButton_CheckedChanged(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e) in
>   e:\EShared\devnet10\VivSnap\SnapInUI\RadioGroupBox.cs:line 70
>          at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr
>   dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner)
>          at SBD.VivSnap.Main.Form1.btnForm1Go_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in e:\EShared\devnet10\VivSnap\Main\Form1.cs:line 36
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr
>   dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)
>          at SBD.VivSnap.Main.Program.Main() in e:\EShared\devnet10\VivSnap\Main\Program.cs:line 18
>          at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()   InnerException:

My code for binding the property is

```
groupBox.DataBindings.Add("Selected", dataSource, PrinterTypeNum, false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

My code for the property is

```
public int PrinterTypeNum  
{
    get
    {
        try
        {
            return (int)this.PrinterType;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    set
    {
        try
        {
            this.PrinterType = (jtVivPrinterEnum)value;
            // the enum goes from 0 to 15
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            this.PrinterType = jtVivPrinterEnum.jtVivPrinterUnknown;
            throw;
        }
    }
}

public jtVivPrinterEnum PrinterType { get; set; }
```

**

[Update] I just discovered that I do not get the error if the property is just as follows.

```
public int PrinterTypeNum { get; set; }
```

My Radio Group class is as follows
//[Best way to databind a group of radiobuttons in WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/675137/best-way-to-databind-a-group-of-radiobuttons-in-winforms)

```
public partial class RadioGroupBox : GroupBox
{
    public RadioGroupBox()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public event EventHandler SelectedChanged = delegate { };
    int _selected;
    public int Selected
    {
        get
        {
            return this._selected;
        }
        set
        {
            int val = 0;
            var radioButton = this.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>()
            .FirstOrDefault(radio => radio.Tag != null
            && int.TryParse(radio.Tag.ToString(), out val) && val == value);

            if (radioButton != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    radioButton.Checked = true;
                    this._selected = val;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Debug.Print(ex.ToString());
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnControlAdded(ControlEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnControlAdded(e);
        var radioButton = e.Control as RadioButton;
        if (radioButton != null)
            radioButton.CheckedChanged += this.radioButton_CheckedChanged;
    }

    void radioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var radio = (RadioButton)sender;
        int val = 0;
        if (radio.Checked && radio.Tag != null
        && int.TryParse(radio.Tag.ToString(), out val))
        {
            this._selected = val;
            this.SelectedChanged(this, new EventArgs());  // raises error when val=10
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Presumably the number of controls you're binding and the number of values you're binding them to doesn't match.  That's only guess though, because you haven't actually shown us how you're performing the binding.  Please provide all the relevant information.

Comment: I added more information. The problem is to do with the property set for the bound property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this error when I changed the `.Visible` property to false in one of data bound components.

The work around is to Remove DataBindings on controls before changing their `.Visible` property to false, then adding the DataBindings back when making them visible again.

Here is code to illustrate the error and how to work around it:

```
void SetupStuff()
{
    BindingSource myBindingSource = new BindingSource();
    // Retrieve my data into a DataTable and add it to the BindingSource
    DataTable myDataTable = GetMyDataTable(); 
    myBindingSource.DataSource = myDataTable.DefaultView;

    // Add DataBindings to Visible components only
    myTextBox.Visible = true;
    myTextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", myBindingSource, "MySecret");
}

void UpdateStuff()
{
    // Update the currently selected data record
    myDataTable.DefaultView[myBindingSource.Position].BeginEdit();
    myDataTable.DefaultView[myBindingSource.Position]["MySecret"] = "Top Secret Meetup " + DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).ToString();
    myDataTable.DefaultView[myBindingSource.Position].EndEdit();
    myDataTable.DefaultView[myBindingSource.Position].AcceptChanges();
    // if myTextBox.Visible, then we can see the message
}

void HideStuff()
{
    myTextBox.Visible = false;
    UpdateStuff();

    // After myDataTable..AcceptChanges(), DataBindings are now BROKEN!
    // This Cleared all data from controls bound to myBindingSource 
    try
    {
        myBindingSource.ResetCurrent();
    }
    catch (Exception brokenBindingSource)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DataBinding broken" + brokenBindingSource.Message);
    }
}

void HideStuff()
{
    if (myTextBox.Visible)
    {
        myTextBox.DataBindings.Remove("MySecret");
        myTextBox.Visible = false;
    }
    UpdateStuff();

    // After myDataTable..AcceptChanges(), DataBindings are now BROKEN!
    // This Cleared all data from controls bound to myBindingSource 
    try
    {
        myBindingSource.ResetCurrent();
    }
    catch (Exception brokenBiSo)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DataBinding is broken" + brokenBiSo.Message);
    }
}

void ShowStuff()
{
    // If I want to make the component visible again, do this:
    if (!myTextBox.Visible)
    {
        myTextBox.Visible = true;
        myTextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", myBindingSource, "MySecret");
    }
}
```

Comment: your answer is probably as good as mine, depending on the particular code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was because I had another property bound that depended on the value selected.
I had "Machine.Mode" as a bound property where the type of the Machine property depended on the PrintType property