# Custom group box not binding to bindingsource

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I need to bind a `GroupBox` to a `BindingSource`, which in turn is bound to the following object:

```
public class CustomerType
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public MemberType MemberType {get; set;}
}

public enum MemberType {Adult, Child}
```

I followed this [answer to create a custom GroupBox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2394429/524861). I also set the data bindings as follows:

```
groupBoxMemberType.DataBindings.Add("Selected", this.bindingSource, "MemberType");
```

However, when loading an existing object, I get the following exception:

> DataBinding cannot find a row in the list that is suitable for all bindings.

The exception occurs when setting the data source:

```
customerType = customerTypeRequest.Load(id);
bindingSource.DataSource = customerType;  //raises exception
```

What am I missing? Is there an alternative to get radio buttons to bind to a datasource, specifically a `BindingSource`?

Comment: When adding the databinding, try passing in true for the last parameter (FormattingEnabled)   public Binding(
 string propertyName,
 Object dataSource,
 string dataMember,
 bool formattingEnabled
)

Comment: @Mangist The exception doesn't occur. However, the changes not are commited to the object.

Comment: are you sure that the problem is with the custom group box? what is the datatype of `customerType` in this row: `bindingSource.DataSource = customerType;`?

Comment: @ZoharPeled customerType is of type CustomerType as explained in the question.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but shouldn't the DataSource be some kind of collection? It seems to me like the problem is you try to bind your BindingSource to a single object instead of to a collection of objects. It's been a while since I last worked with BindingSource, so maybe I'm wrong on that one

Comment: @ZoharPeled I'm using the BindingSource to bind to a single object. I don't know if there's a better way to bind an object to the controls, but it's working.

Comment: Oh, I see, you want to bind the radio buttons to the enum. I understand my mistake now, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the changed code:

```
[DefaultBindingProperty("Selected")]
public class RadioGroupBox : GroupBox
{
    #region events

    [Description("Occurs when the selected value changes.")]
    public event SelectedChangedEventHandler SelectedChanged;

    public class SelectedChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public int Selected { get; private set; }

        internal SelectedChangedEventArgs(int selected)
        {
            this.Selected = selected;
        }
    }
    public delegate void SelectedChangedEventHandler(object sender, SelectedChangedEventArgs e);

    #endregion

    private int selected;

    [Browsable(false)]
    [Bindable(BindableSupport.Yes, BindingDirection.TwoWay)]
    [Description("The selected value associated with this control."), Category("Data")]
    public int Selected
    {
        get { return selected; }
        set
        {
            int val = 0;
            var radioButton = this.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>()
                .FirstOrDefault(radio =>
                    radio.Tag != null
                   && int.TryParse(radio.Tag.ToString(), out val) && val == value);

            if (radioButton != null)
            {
                radioButton.Checked = true;
                selected = val;
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnControlAdded(ControlEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnControlAdded(e);

        var radioButton = e.Control as RadioButton;
        if (radioButton != null)
            radioButton.CheckedChanged += radioButton_CheckedChanged;
    }

    protected void OnSelectedChanged(SelectedChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (SelectedChanged != null)
            SelectedChanged(this, e);
    }

    private void radioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var radio = (RadioButton)sender;
        int val = 0;
        if (radio.Checked && radio.Tag != null
             && int.TryParse(radio.Tag.ToString(), out val))
        {
            selected = val;
            OnSelectedChanged(new SelectedChangedEventArgs(selected));
        }
    }
}
```

Further to setting the `Tag` property to the corresponding int value of the enum, you need to subscribe to the SelectedChanged event in your form, eg:

```
private void radioGroupBoxMemberType_SelectedChanged(object sender, SelectedChangedEventArgs e)
{
    customerType.MemberType = (MemberType)e.Selected;
}
```

Improvements to this class would be:

1. Inherit from RadioButton and use a new property instead of the `Tag` property.
2. Access and set the bindingsource property directly in the control to avoid subscribing to the event.